Why is nativeEvent not registering keystrokes?
I've set up my application to print a debug statement when clicking on F8 or F7 on my keyboard. However, nativeEvent doesn't seem to pick up on any keyboard input, why is this?
mainwindow.cpp snippet:
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QKeySequence defaultKeySequence("F9");
    ui->keySequenceEdit->setKeySequence(defaultKeySequence);

    registerHotKey(100, 0, VK_F8);
    registerHotKey(101, 0, VK_F7);

}


bool MainWindow::registerHotKey(int id, int modifiers, int key) {
    if (!RegisterHotKey((HWND)MainWindow::winId(), id, modifiers, key)) {
        qDebug() << "Failed to register hotkey with ID:" << id;
        return false;
    }
    qDebug() << "Registered hotkey with ID:" << id;
    return true;
}


bool MainWindow::nativeEvent(const QByteArray &eventType, void *message, long *result){
    Q_UNUSED(eventType);
    Q_UNUSED(result);
    qDebug() << "Received message:";
    return false;
}

mainwindow.h snippet:
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();


    Ui::MainWindow *getUi() const;


protected:
    bool nativeEvent(const QByteArray &eventType, void *message, long *result);

private slots:
    // Stuff

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

Upon running the application, the output yields:
STARTING APPLICATION!
Hotkey changed to:  QKeySequence("F9")
Registered hotkey with ID: 100
Registered hotkey with ID: 101

When pressing F8 and F7, no debug output is displayed.

For testing, I've copied over the files: main.cpp, mainwindow.ui, mainwindow.h, and mainwindow.cpp from this repo: https://github.com/Onebeld/QuickAutoclicker/tree/master
into a NEW QT Create project. When I build and click on F8 and F7 it doesn't register keystrokes either. However, their executable works perfectly fine and does register F7 and F8. Could it be something to do with how I'm compiling the code in QT?

Can you add override keyword to check if your signature is matching? In Qt docs the last argument is of type qintptr *result which might be different than long*.

@pptaszni Using override on the nativeEvent declaration in mainwindow.h yields the error: non-virtual member function marked 'override' hides virtual member function

@pptaszni Changing it from long to qintptr has produced progress. It now responds to F7 and F8, however upon starting the application the output is flooded with "Received message:" despite nothing being pressed

F7 and F8 keypresses aren't the only native events... You have to filter.

So, problem solved I guess? You are not checking the event types, so ofc your qDebug will trigger on every event.

@pptaszni Thats the weird thing, it doesn't. Upon starting the application it spams the "Received message", then it stops. After, it will only respond to F7 and F8 which is intended, and it will ignore all other keystrokes. Unless those nativeEvents aren't keystrokes, and my program only after booting "responds" to keystroke events that match my parameters

Debug it, check what kind of events are captured, print their messages, etc ... It might be simply expected behavior from ms windows POV.

@pptaszni Good thinking, I can take it from here. Consider it solved. You can post an answer if you want and I'll check it

For Qt6 the signature of the method to override is:
bool QWidget::nativeEvent(const QByteArray &eventType, void *message, qintptr *result)

If on your platform std::is_same_v<qintptr, long> is false, then you are overloading or shadowing the method instead of overriding it. To avoid this kind of mistakes, it's a good practice to use override keyword:
// this will result in compilation error:
bool nativeEvent(const QByteArray &eventType, void *message, long *result) override;

